# Error "too few arguments to function call, at least argument 'format' must be specified" C programming

Tags: c, function, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>

//declare functions

int add_two_ints(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    //ask the user for input
    
    printf("give an integer: ");
    int x = get_int();

    printf("give me another integer: ");
    int y = get_int();
    //call function

    int z = add_two_ints(x, y);
    

    printf("the result of %i plus %i is %i!\n", x, y, z);


}

//function
int add_two_ints(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}
```

when i run the program i get the error too few arguments to function call, at least argument format must be specified

this is a simple function with only two arguments being pass since im new to c programming im trying to figure out where i made the mistake.
whats is the correct way to write function ?

Comment: I am pretty sure the error message is even pointing you to a specific function/line.

Comment: @zois It's in `cs50.h`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I missed that, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_int` function included as part of CS50 expects a string for a prompt, which you're not passing.  So instead of this:

```
printf("give an integer: ");
int x = get_int();
```

You want this:

```
int x = get_int("give an integer: ");
```

And similarly for reading `y`.

Comment: thank you for your answer i realize after i saw a previews code problem

Answer (score 0):

I just realize what I was doing wrong the `get_int` was expecting a string so I just deleted the `printf` statement and put in on to the `get_int` so now when it runs it works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

//declare functions

int add_two_ints(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
//ask the user for input
    
    
int x = get_int("give an integer: ");


int y = get_int("give an integer: ");

int z = add_two_ints(x, y);

printf("the result of %i plus %i is %i!\n", x, y, z);


}

int add_two_ints(int a, int b)
{
int sum = a + b;
return sum;
}
```